# Windows 10 start menu folder suddenly empty

Tags: windows-10, powershell, start-menu

I frequently use Windows PowerShell, and this morning when I went to start it by right-clicking on the start menu button and selecting "Windows PowerShell", I'm getting an error:

"Windows cannot find '`C:\Users\(this comp)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk`'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

Checking the directory `C:\Users\(this comp)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, it's completely empty. There's nothing there.

In contrast, the directory `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` does have a bunch of sub-directories, including Windows PowerShell directory with the .lnk file inside it (which works fine).

I do not know what exactly happened. I did try yesterday the Atomic Heart DXR demo, which I then uninstalled. I also tried Nvidia's "Elevator Demo". Could it possibly be that they messed up that start menu directory?

Or could it perhaps be that the first directory above (which the start menu option is referring to) has always been empty, but the link in the start menu has for some reason changed to point to it? (I think there was a Windows update recently, but for the life of me I can't remember if I have tried to start PowerShell between then and now.)

A couple of days ago I did create a Windows restore point before updating the Nvidia display driver. (I have also done so at semi-regular intervals prior to that, usually always before updating said driver.) I did try right-clicking on the `Programs` directory mentioned above (which is empty) and selecting "Restore previous versions", but it says there are no previous versions. (This might or might not indicate that this directory has always been empty, and that the change has happened to that start menu entry itself. I have no idea.)

I'm a bit at a loss here. I don't know which one of those two scenarios has happened (ie. did something erase the first `Programs` directory above, or did something (eg. windows update?) change the link in the start menu's right-click menu to point to the wrong directory?) Or is this something else? I also don't know how to fix this. I don't even know how to change the right-click menu of the start menu button.

I am able to launch PowerShell via other methods (such as writing it in the search menu), but this is both inconvenient and a bit worrisome. Something has changed, and I don't know why, nor whether I should be worried about it, nor how to fix it.

Comment: I asked this same question on the official Microsoft forums, and got somewhat similar answers. It seems there isn't really a way to "rebuild" a start menu folder that has been emptied for some reason (apparently not even if you had created a restore point recently, for some reason). One person simply suggested as a very lightweight fix to copy the contents of the Default profile start menu folder into the one that has been emptied. Not very eager to do anything more drastic (such as resetting Windows), I did that. At least PowerShell now starts normally again. I hope nothing else is broken.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PowerShell code issue, which is what we are here to help with. This is an environment corruption issue.

PowerShell is not the problem nor can it correct it based on your description of the path to your current state.

Based on where you are, unless you have an offline restore / backup, you are going to have to rebuild either using System Refresh or from scratch. Either choice still means reinstalling stuff later.

This UNC ---

> C:\Users(this comp)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs

--- is always populated by default. Thus should never be empty.

***My last suggestion, before the rebuild thing, is to try this:***
Create an new admin user

1. Logon with that admin user
2. Backup all else in the corrupted profile
3. delete the corrupted user profile
4. Delete that user associated with that profile
5. add that user back
6. log on with that user
7. Check out your resources

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same problem and I think it's the Atomic Heart DXR demo! It installed itself in Appdata. After one run, I uninstalled from its directory, later I realized my search is not working. I thought it is some kind of indexing issue, but no.. user Start Menu was totally empty!. All I can think now, especially after seeing that you also tried and uninstalled Atomic Heart DXR demo, there was a problem with its uninstaller. I will copy and paste system shortcuts from default user, but I hope it didn't mess up anything else.

Comment: This is what I suspect too. (The other suspect is the elevator demo, but I think the Atomic Heart demo is more likely, because it uses an installer and uninstaller.) This could be tested eg. in a virtual machine, but I don't have one installed... Strangely, I can't find with google anybody else having experienced this problem.